# how to load and include some input values from the originating form to the fancybox that has submit button?

Tags: php, jquery, yii, fancybox

i have 3 input boxes e.g 
name, age, address then it has a button at the bottom named 'apply'
...now when i click the 'apply' button, a fancybox will pop up
and has another 3 set of input boxes e.g
company, department, supervisor..
and then it has a 'cancel' and 'submit' button at the bottom ...

my question is, how will I include the name,age,address to the fancybox along with the
company, department, supervisor when I click the 'apply' button ?
because the name, age, address are from a different area, and when I click the 'submit' button  I want the name, age, address, company, department, supervisor datas

here's the code of the first form

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name/>
<input type="text" name="age value="" id="age"/>
<input type="text" name="address" value="" id="address" />
<a href="#anotherform" id="firstform" class="form-btn">Apply</a>
```

here's the code of the second form for the fancy box

```
    <form action ="#" method="post">
    company: <input type="text" name="company" id="company" /><br/>
    department: <input type="text" name="department" id="department" /><br/>
    supervisor: <input type="text" name="supervisor" id="supervisor" /><br/>
    <input type="button" name="cancelapply" id="submitapply" value="cancel" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="button" name="submitapply" id="submitapply" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

and this is my fancy box code

```
    jQuery("a#firstform").fancybox({
        'titlePosition' : 'inside',
        'transitionIn' : 'none',
        'transitionOut' : 'none',
        'hideOnOverlayClick' : false,
        'hideOnContentClick' : false,
        'showCloseButton' : true,

                    //HOW TO PASS THE name,age,address to the fancybox when i click the
                    //'apply' button.
                    //and then when i submit the fancy box, i can get the
                    // 6 values ?

    });
```

Comment: Is this a single page app, or is there a post to the server involved?

Comment: single page..after the fancy box got submitted, that's the only time i think there's a post involve then

Comment: just to confirm, are you using fancybox v1.3.4?

Comment: yes, that's the exact version

Answer (score 0):

Put the fancybox code inside the first form, remove the  tags on the second form and it should submit with your data as one form even when they are hidden. So you should only have one form tag.

Answer (score 0):

You already have company, dept, supervisor showing, correct? Then this might do the trick if I understand your question:

Changes to the fancy box

```
<form action ="#" method="post">
  company: <input type="text" name="company" id="company" /><br/>
  department: <input type="text" name="department" id="department" /><br/>
  supervisor: <input type="text" name="supervisor" id="supervisor" /><br/>

  name: <input type="text" id="name-verify/>
  age: <input type="text" id="age-verify"/>
  address: <input type="text" id="address-verify" />

  <input type="button" name="cancelapply" id="submitapply" value="cancel"/>
  <input type="button" name="submitapply" id="submitapply" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and some jQuery changes:

```
$('#firstform').click(function() {
  $('#name-verify').val($('#name').val());
  $('#age-verify').val($('#age').val());
  $('#address-verify').val($('#address').val());
});
```